# How to set dialog (Custom) a glittering effect?

Tags: java, android, graphic

In my android app, I've designed some layouts to set the custom dialog. But I face some problems while making border with glittering effect.

I've set the following style to my dialog:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
<item name="android:windowFrame">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFrame">@drawable/alertbgc</item>
```

In the java snippet,I added the lines as follows:

```
final Dialog mydialog= new Dialog(this,R.style.MyDialog);
mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

But with this snippets I'm getting very dark background (I used nine patch images too, but no use). Please help me providing your ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the glow effect ?

Comment: s. Absolutely correct

Comment: @Rakesh L can you provide the link of image or application which use this type of dialog.?

Comment: please look at this . I need like this .. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HANJUtgQCs0/UHKgR7J75PI/AAAAAAAAC_I/gqCd2moDM2w/s1600/Android++Dialog+-+Custom+Dialog+for+User+Login.png

I cant get this border with the style I given.

Comment: add glowing type of background image to do that thing

Comment: I used to do like that .In my dialog I've set a spinner .if I select an Item.that background seems darker and if select an another item,It seems much darker and doesn't look well :(